# Dash graph does not display after adding an update_graph() function

Tags: dataframe, jupyter-notebook, callback, plotly-dash, dashboard

Using Dash in Jupyter Notebook, I'm trying to make an app where the x-axis of a bar chart is updated based on the Dash RangeSlider component. 
When I run the code, the app displays a working slider, but a blank graph:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VeF0.png

I've included my code below- any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
import os
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output 
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
import keyring
import plotly 
import plotly.express as px

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Connecting to my work's DB, I built a DataFrame & saved it to the variable 'df' 
#'df' has two columns, df.start_year and df.members_joined 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Launch the application 
app_name = 'dash-postgresqldataplot'
  
app = Dash(__name__)
app.title = 'Membership Trends'

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create a Dash layout 
app.layout = html.Div([
    # a header and a paragraph 
    html.Div([
        html.H1("This is my first interactive dashboard!"),
        html.P("Using a range slider with a callback function to update the date range on the plotly bar graph")
    ],
        style = {'padding' : '50px' ,
                              'backgroundColor' : '#3aaab2'}),
   # adding a plot
    dcc.Graph(
    id='the_graph'
    ),
    
   # range slider 
    dcc.RangeSlider(
                    min= df['start_year'].min(),
                    max= df['start_year'].max(),
                    step=None,
                    value=[2014,2021], #default values initially chosen 
                    marks= {2014:'2014',2015:'2015',2016:'2016',2017:'2017',2018:'2018',
                            2019:'2019',2020:'2020',2021:'2021'},
                    allowCross=False,
                    id='the_slider'
                   )
        
])
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
# Add callback functions to tie the range slider to the plot output 
@app.callback(
    Output('the_graph', 'figure'),
    Input('the_slider', 'value'))
    
def update_graph(years_chosen):
    #filtering the data
    dff = df[(df.start_year >= years_chosen[0]) & (df.start_year <= years_chosen[1])]   
    #updating the plot 
    barchart = px.bar(
        dff,
        x="year",
        y="mems"
    )

    return (barchart)

# Add the server clause 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out I just needed to read the docs for the px.bar()!

I had assumed because of the parenthesis that x = "" and y="" were just naming the axes of the graph, but they actually take a DataFrame Series as an argument.

So, by changing from x= "year" and y="mems" to x="start_year" and y="members_joined" to match the df, it now runs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).